# Limit amount of childs in Rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

I want to limit the number of childs for a JSON response rendered with rabl

```
collection @vehicles
attributes :name

child(:positions) do
   attributes :lat, :lon
end
```

A Vehicle has_many positions and a position belongs to a vehicle.
Now I want to output only the last position in the JSON.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar situation in my models and here is how I deal with it.

Make the index action extend the show action. In `vehicles/index.json.rabl`

```
collection @vehicles
extends 'vehicles/show'
```

`vehicles/show.json.rabl`

```
object @vehicle
attributes :name
child @vehicle.positions.first => :position do
   attributes :lat, :long
end
```

Comment: Now I have found another solution. I put a function into the model named last_position and simply set this in the attributes.